# How to construct a sequence of yes/no questions in dialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

If I want to create a long sequence (at least ten) of yes and no questions in dialogFlow, using webhook to store results, do I need to create an intent for each question or could this be done programatically from the webhook somehow, enforcing the order of the sequence in a better way and possibly making the code less extensive?

A sequence of questions like:
*Is cucumber a fruit? Yes/No, Are there flying fish? Yes/No, e.t.c.*

Comment: Completely rephrased to make it more clear.